# Create .pfx Private Key Certificates for Azure Web app

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I purchased certificate from godaddy and currently I have the following files

- xxx.crt
- xxx.pem
- xxx.p7b
- generated-csr.txt
- generated-private-key.txt

I am having a hardtime setting it up in my azure web app, it requires me to upload .pfx (Private Key Certificates)

I tried openssl

`openssl pkcs12 -export -out {name}.pfx -inkey generated-private-key.txt in xxx.crt`

It says unable to load private key, is there any process needed to create private key using that generated-private-key.txt ?

---

UPDATE: Resolved the issue using this reference
https://medium.com/@joshyates1980/apply-ssl-t0-azure-web-application-8cc72d886993

Comment: If the reply solves the problem, you could accept it or let me know if you need further help or share your solution if it fixed itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have not tried it yet but I can add some points to it. I solved the issue using this reference https://medium.com/@joshyates1980/apply-ssl-t0-azure-web-application-8cc72d886993

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following methods:

**With OpenSSL**, you could get a similar question from https://sg.godaddy.com/community/SSL-And-Security/Install-Godaddy-SSL-on-IIS-10-Windows-Server-2019/td-p/147344

- Open generated-private-key.txt in Notepad++ and change the encoding from `UTF-8-BOM` to `UTF-8`
  [image]
- Run this command: `openssl pkcs12 -export -out {name}.pfx -inkey generated-private-key.txt in xxx.crt`

Alternatively, **[Install your certificate in MMC and export the PFX file](https://pk.godaddy.com/help/windows-install-codedriver-signing-certificate-and-create-pfx-file-2698)**

[image]